# Spring boot custom converter not called

Tags: spring-boot, scala, google-cloud-platform

I'm getting this exception on my project with Springboot + Scala.

> No converter found capable of converting from type
> [com.google.protobuf.ByteString$LiteralByteString] to type
> [java.lang.String]

I ve tried to implement a custom converter and registering it, both with GenericConveter and Converter<T,U>

```
@Component
public class GcpStringGenericConverter implements GenericConverter {
    @Override
    public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
        Set<ConvertiblePair> convertiblePairs = new HashSet<>(1);
        convertiblePairs.add(new ConvertiblePair(ByteString.class, String.class));
        return convertiblePairs;
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        return ((ByteString) source).toStringUtf8();
    }
}
```

I tried to register the converter in 2 different ways:

- On a post constructor on the Object of my main class:

```
object DistributionBatchMainClass {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    SpringApplication.run(classOf[DistributionBatch], args: _*)
  }

  import org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService

  @PostConstruct def postConstruct(gcpStringGenericConverter: GcpStringGenericConverter): Unit = { 
    val dcs = DefaultConversionService.getSharedInstance.asInstanceOf[DefaultConversionService]
    dcs.addConverter(gcpStringGenericConverter)
  }

}
```

- Before running Spring application:

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val dcs = DefaultConversionService.getSharedInstance.asInstanceOf[DefaultConversionService]
    dcs.addConverter(gcpStringGenericConverter)
    SpringApplication.run(classOf[DistributionBatch], args: _*)
  }
```

In both cases it seems the converter is not properly set up and I
still get the error:

> No converter found capable of converting from type
> [com.google.protobuf.ByteString$LiteralByteString] to type
> [java.lang.String]

Any ideas?